# Log4Net logs incorrect data

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, log4net-appender

I have a WCF service where in I use Log4Net for logging information to Sql Server database. I use Log4Net's GlobalContext to log some extra information, like Transaction Name, Status, Message, and few other stuff. Some of the important transactions within this system are Read, Write and Login.

The log should look like:

- "Read"    --------     "Success"       --------     "Read xxx customer data"
- "Write"  --------      "Success"  --------          "Written xxx customer's data"
- "Login"  --------      "Failure"      --------      "User session already exists."

Everything works fine when I run my normal tests - the logs are written to the database perfectly. However, recently I did a load test by using JMeter. The above mentioned three transactions were tested in 100 concurrent threads for 3 minutes. When I checked the DB logs, I found that some of the information were logged incorrectly.

Ex:

- "Read" --------       "Success"  --------          "User session already exists."
- "Write" --------       "Success" --------           "Read xxx customer data"

Is this an issue with Log4Net GlobalContext not being thread safe? I tried using ThreadContext instead of GlobalContext, but looks like lots of information were not logged.

Comment: Looks like that the messages were mixed up during writing time to the db because you did write concurrently to the db. You need to take a closer look with a debugger and inspect the whole chain.

Comment: GlobalContext is thread-safe as per doc http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html

Comment: @Mark: I have seen that. But, the issue I face force me to think different!!!

Comment: Is it possible to post some sample code?

Comment: I always assumed that thread-safe meant that these methods would not blow up or throw exceptions when called from multiple threads, but since the storage is global, changes in one thread will affect other threads.  So your results are what I would expect. As for threadContext not working either, I think this is a common problem and caused by **thread agility** where something you consider a single process can switch between threads. You can read more here  http://blog.marekstoj.com/2011/12/log4net-contextual-properties-and.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LogicalThreadContext did the trick for me!